# Caching streamed movie on iPhone

Tags: ios, caching, video-streaming

In a few days I'm supposed to start working on a new app and one of the requirements seems a bit odd to me. User will be able to watch streamed videos that my client also has on his site. Problem is, app has to save it and later, when user is offline, he should have the option to watch it again. Any ideas how am I supposed to save that (streamed) movie to memory?

Edit: The movie can even be 1 hour long.